# Dynamic bayesian model conditional independence

Tags: machine-learning, probability, self-study, graphical-model, bayesian-network

I have just started learning probabilistic graphical models, so my knowledge of this subject is relatively weak. Hope I don't make any mistakes in my question.

Given the Dynamic Bayesian model shown below, suppose that $O^{(1)}$, $O^{(2)}$, $X^{(1)}$, $X^{(2)}$ are not observed, then $O^{(2)}$ is not independent of $O^{(1)}$. I.e $P(O^{(2)}|O^{(1)},X^{(2)}) \neq P(O^{(2)}|X^{(2)})$ because there is an active trail from $O^{(2)}$ to $O^{(1)}$

[image]

Suppose that only $O^{(1)}$ is observed, then is $O^{(2)}$ independent of $O^{(1)}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... suppose that $O^{(1)}$, $O^{(2)}$, $X^{(1)}$, $X^{(2)}$ are not observed, then $O^{(2)}$ is not independent of $O^{(1)}$. I.e $P(O^{(2)}|O^{(1)},X^{(2)}) \neq P(O^{(2)}|X^{(2)})$

Actually, according to the graph, $P(O^{(2)}|O^{(1)},X^{(2)}) = P(O^{(2)}|X^{(2)})$ because $X^{(2)}$ is observed. However, in your statement, you say it's not. The correct mathematical translation should be $P(O^{(2)}|O^{(1)})\neq P(O^{(2)})$.

> Suppose that only $O^{(1)}$ is observed, then is $O^{(2)}$ independent of $O^{(1)}$?

When a random variable is observed, it's not random anymore and everything else will be independent of it.

Comment: thank you for your help. Why would you say that $X^{(2)}$ is observed ? If we were to take the diagram as a hidden markov model $X$ would be latent ? Also, if $X^{(2)}$ is not observed then $O^{(2)}$ is not independent of $O^{(1)}$?

Comment: Being observed depends on the expression, not the graph. If you say $p(x|y)$, it means $y$ is observed. If $X^{(2)}$ is not observed, yes, the outputs are dependent.

Comment: Ahh i see thank you for clarifying. Can I assume the joint probability of the model is $$P(X^{(1)}, X^{(2)},O^{(1)},O^{(2)}) = P(X^{(1)})P(O^{(1)}|X^{(1)})P(X^{(2)}|X^{(1)})P(O^{(2)}|X^{(2)})$$

Comment: Yes, that's what the graph describes.